# XMPP chat client using phonegap tool in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: javascript, cordova, xmpp, windows-phone-7.1, jsjac

In my WindowsPhone7.1 project, there is a XMPP chat module. I designed chat window using HTML/CSS perfectly.

To connect with Jabber server(Openfire), I used [JsJaC library](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsjac-javascript-jabber-client-library).

How to integrate it with the Windows Phone 7.1 project?

Should I include library script files in `WWW` folder?

Can I simply write my client script in cordavo-1.5.0.js after that?